# Visual Studio missing most Javascript editing functions in one solution

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense

I have a bizarre issue where a websites JavaScript files are missing many of the editor functions such as:

1. handles around code blocks; buttons that allow collapse/expansion
2. correct line breaks; when pressing enter the cursor goes to the next line but first character position rather than nested per previous line
3. Keyboard shortcuts missing
4. Intellisense missing
5. The dotted line showing the start/end of a nest

and various others.

What I did to get to this:

1. I have a website in a solution, call it solution A and the JavaScript editing is normal.

This website is going to be moved into a new solution along with other projects.

2. I created a new empty solution (solution B) and added some solution folders.
3. I copied the website (via windows exploroer) from solution A to solution B.
4. Modified the namespace within the csproj file using notepad
5. Added this website as an existing project to solution B
6. Performed a find/replace through the code to adjust the namespace to the new one set in D above.

Now when I open my JavaScript files I get none of the functionality listed above.

I have verified that the Text Editor / Javascript/Typescript options are good.

The 2 images below are from copies of the same file in different solutions both running on Visual Studio 2017. The images demonstrate the lack of the collapse/expand button and the dotted lines. Interestingly, all color is correct.

**Any ideas what might cause this?**

**Good JavaScript**
[image: Correct JavaScript file]

**Bad JavaScript**
[image: Bad JavaScript File]

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around a colleague found this link talking about a very similar issue - [JavaScript intellisense still not working](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/85087/javascript-intellisense-still-not-working.html)

One of the comments mentioned disabling the 'Language Service' function.

I did this, and sure enough all functionality has returned.

I am not going to mark this as an answer because i've had to disable one thing to cure another. This is just what i have had to do to get JS to edit correctly.

What I am doing right now us updating Visual Studio. It's currently 15.0.26430.4 and 15.4.27004.2002 has just been released. With any luck this resolves the issue.

[image]

**UPDATE**

After updating Visual Studio all is working correctly. Can only assume there was an issue with the Language Service.